# How do I start AWS EC2 instance using awscli interface?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Am trying to start my AWS EC2 instance using the **awscli** interface without any luck. This is my command:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids <my-instance-id>
```

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidInstanceID.NotFound) when calling the StopInstances operation: The instance ID '<my-instance-id>' does not exist
```

Am getting the same error when I use the **boto3** library.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) syntax is:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-abcd1234 --region us-west-2
```

(If you have a default region defined, then you don't need `--region`.)

Doing via [boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.start_instances):

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = 'us-west-2')
ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=['i-abcd1234'])
```